# JQuery: scrolling animation problem

Tags: jquery, scroll, effects, slide

I've written these 2 JQuery functions which are supposed to take 9  blocks with IDs set from "C1" to "C9" and scroll them upwards until they reach the top and then each block that reaches the top should go back and start again. The strange thing is each time they start over the space between the blocks gets larger until everything gets messed up. I'm new to JQuery and I would appreciate any help or even better ideas on how I should do this.
This is the code:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Some JQuery Practice</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" type="text/css">
        <style>
            #BOX{
                position:absolute;
                width:700px;
                height:200px;
                top:100px;
                overflow:hidden;
                background-color:#D3C79D;
                -moz-border-radius:30px;
            }
            .content{

                font-family:Tahoma;
                font-size: 11px;
                position:relative;
                width:660px;
                top:200px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function OneGoesUp(target){
                if(target.position().top == 0){
                    target.css({"top":"270"});
                }
                target.animate({
                    "top": "-=1"
                }, 10, function(){OneGoesUp(target)});
            }
            function GoUp(){
                for(var i=1;i<10;i++){
                    var str = "#c";
                    str += i;
                    $(str).text(str);
                    OneGoesUp($(str));
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="GoUp();"> 
        <div id="BOX">
        <div id="c1" class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
        <div id="c2" class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
        <div id="c3" class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
        <div id="c4" class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
        <div id="c5" class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
        <div id="c6" class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
        <div id="c7" class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
        <div id="c8" class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
        <div id="c9" class="content"><p>ghghjghjghj</p></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The GoUp() function gets called once and that's when the page loads. Do I have to use the Cycle plugin for such an effect?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your html as well.

Comment: I edited the post and added the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be easier with **absolute position on the .content class** (this way positions on the screen are more consistent and don't depend one on each other among the div.content elements, so i suggest you update your CSS accordingly), and then the following modifications in the JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('.content').each(function(i){
            $(this).text($(this).attr('id'));
            $(this).css('top', 15*i + 'px'); //initial position, Y-space of 15px beteween each div
            OneGoesUp($(this));
        });
    }
);

function OneGoesUp(target){
    if(parseInt(target.css('top')) == 0){
        target.css({'top':'270px'});
    }
    target.animate({
        "top": "-=1"
    }, 10, function(){OneGoesUp(target)});
}
</script>
```

and finally remove `onload` from the `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Smooth Scrolling</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container{
            width:300px;
            margin:0 auto;  
                  }
        .section{
            margin-top:60px;
                }
    .navigation{
        position: fixed;
        background:white;
        padding:20px 20px;
        width:100%;
        margin-top:0px;
        top:0px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="#html">HTML</a>
    <a href="#javascript">JavaScript</a>
    <a href="#jquery">jQuery</a>
    <a href="#php">PHP</a>
    <a href="#css">CSS</a>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <h1 id="html">HTML</h1>
            <p>
            put your text about html here


            </p>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <h1 id="javascript">JavaScript</h1>
    <p>
            put your javascript details here.
            </p>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <h1 id="jquery">jQuery</h1>
    <p>
            Put your details about javascript here
            </p>

</div>
<div class="section">
    <h1 id="php">PHP</h1>
    <p>
            put your details about php here
            </p>

</div>
<div class="section">
    <h1 id="css">CSS</h1>
    <p>put your details </p>

</div>      
</div>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("href");
        var offset = 60;
        var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target}, 3000);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```